# Is there a way to read input from the console to multiple variables similiar to how you do it in C++ or C?

Tags: c#

In C or C++ you can read console input to multiple variables in a single line, I will show you an example where the program ask the user their name and age and then simply output the users input to the console window.

C

```
char name[100];
int age = 0;
printf("Hello, please write your name and age on the screen\n");
scanf("%s %d",name, &age);
printf("your name is %s and you are %d years old", name, age);
return 0;
```

C++

```
std::string name;
int age;
std::cout << "Hello, please write your name and age on the screen" << 
std::endl;
std::cin >>name>>age;
std::cout <<"Your name is " <<name<< " and you are " <<age<<" years old";
return 0;
```

In both C and C++ you can read and store values to both "name" and "age" with a single scanf or cin, however in C# i need to split the sentence and read from the console twice, look at the following example:

```
string name;
int age;
Console.WriteLine("Hello, please write your name");
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Now write your age");
age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0} and you are {1} years old", name, age);
Console.ReadLine();
```

To store values to "name" and "age" I had to do two ReadLines, one for each value.
The closest way to read multiple values wih one ReadLine was to first read both the name and age into one variable and then split the sentence like this:

```
string input;
string name;
int age;
Console.WriteLine("Hello, please write your name and age on the screen");
input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] split = input.Split(' ');
 name = split[0];
 age =  int.Parse(split[1]);
Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0} and you are {1} years old", name, age);
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, this is not equivalent to the way you can read multiple inputs in C and C++. I do not know if splitting a variable is the closest way to mimic the way you do it in C and C++. Something I am looking for would be:

```
Console.Readline(name,age);
```

This would not work because the Readline method is not written to do this. On top of that the Readline would still have to be stored somewhere so we would still have to split an another variable.

So is there a way to provide a similiar input in C# to C and C++ when you want to read multiple values? Or is splitting the way to go?

Comment: Splitting... but you can split using a regex which feels much more like a format string (however all the results will still be strings, to be converted separately).

Comment: I'm genuinely curious; in C/C++, when you do something like that, how does the user enter the two values? They must have to press some key to show they're done with the name, right?

Comment: The cin and scanf will "pause" the program. The user must press enter to "confirm" their input.

Comment: So, much like `ReadLine()` then. If you don't output anything between the two `ReadLine()` statements, it would work pretty much the same, no?

Comment: Not really, I understood your question wrong. The scanf and cin will in these examples split the input with spaces. When you press enter you allow the program to execute its next orders.

Comment: Okay, well it seems like the split would work. Thanks for the info!